# run vs code as root

Tags: 18.04, server, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with my virtual server (OS: Ubuntu 18.04).

Recently, I wanted to use VS Code and I installed it and I used the command:

```bash
sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"
```

How can I return this command and make it like the first day?

Comment: you can delete your config folders created by vscode. read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1113022/how-do-i-remove-vs-code-settings-from-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio Code will run as a root using the following command:

```
$ sudo code . --user-data-dir='.' --no-sandbox
```